# Git does not ask me for gpg passphrase and fails my commit

Tags: git, gnupg

When I do `git commit -a -S -m "Commit Message"`, I get this error:

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Username (Gpg Key) <email-id>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 2487BE7C, created 2016-10-03

error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

But, it doesn't even ask/prompts for my passphrase when I commit. So, how and where do I enter my passphrase while using gpg's `-S` flag?

Comment: Are you sure gpg can read input? If stdin is closed, you would see the above error message. If the git command is not run in an interactive shell, then you might need to have gpg-agent running in order to handle the passphrase input.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Possible to tell how to start it please?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had the similar thing. I had the gpg and gpg2 binaries, both pointing to GPG version 2.0.30. I wasn't being prompted for my passphrase.

In your bash profile (I did it in my .zshrc file) add the following line:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me in my bash on macOS.

Comment: Forgot all about `.zshrc` I've been trying this from other posts but in my `.bashrc` whoops! This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

It stopped prompting me, so I had to kill the daemon

```sh
ps aux | grep gpg
mark              3129   0.0  0.0  4397952    820   ??  Ss    8Mar19   0:28.84 gpg-agent --homedir /Users/Mark/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
mark             18137   0.0  0.0  4286492    848 s000  R+    3:43pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn gpg
```

then

```sh
sudo kill -9 3129
```

Then it worked. It may be a slightly different issue.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Seems like I exited the previous prompt in a bad way which confused the daemon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OSX. It seems like a gpg update (of brew) changed to location of gpg to gpg1, you can change the binary where git looks up the gpg:

```
git config --global gpg.program gpg1
```

*See [this medium blog post](https://medium.com/jubianchi-fr/mac-osx-and-gpg2-d5f719fc596#.a9xhteo18).*

Comment: For me it's still gpg but it won't ask for password and fail. Any other recommendation?